# Is there anything like AWS Direct Connect in Azure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure

AWS Direct Connect allows physical connections and BGP setup to connect AWS cloud with on-premise DC or customer's private cloud. I wonder if there's anything like this in MS Azure cloud. Not VPN based..

Comment: You should ask this on ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind-of.

It is announced as a future plan to support, but not yet accessible to customers. I believe this is what you are asking for: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/news/press/2013/sep13/09-18msattpr.aspx

Hopefully we can see this announcements moving forward in the next year. Offering this solution to regions other than USA will also be interesting development of this solution, but currently nothing can be found on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

As the cloud continues to be embraced by customers and partners around the world we are seeking to help them connect to their off-premise investments. Today, providers such as TW Telecom, AT&T, and Level 3 grant their clients the ability to connect to AWS or Windows Azure with scalable and flexible connectivity. Recently, Level 3 released ExpressRoute; a new service that allows customers to utilize a private connection from an Equinox Data Center to the Windows Azure Cloud. This service is similar in nature to the AWS direct connect service that was released a few years ago, providing a private network route to hosted cloud services that bypasses the public Internet.

ExpressRoute aims to reduce latency, and increase the speed in which clients can access their applications. To achieve this goal, Level 3 provides the client with 1 gigabit or 10 gigabit connection from an Equinox Data Center in San Jose to Windows Azure increasing your network throughput for large workloads. Today, Windows Azure does not offer multiple VPN’s into their cloud. To compensate for this issue, consolidating and connecting to the Azure cloud with a private connection ensures the transfer of your data.

Ref. from http://fastblue.com/cloud-connectivity-aws-direct-connect-and-windows-azure-express-route/